# If list object is zero then set another value

Tags: c#

I have a List,

```
List<Model.UserSetUp> objUserSetUp = objUserSetUp1.Select(m => new Model.UserSetUp()
{
    Id = m.UserId,
    FirstName = m.FirstName,
    SurName = m.SurName,
    Computer_Name = m.Computer_Name,
    IP_Address = m.IP_Address,
    LogInTime = m.LogInTime,
    UserName = Decrypt(m.UserName),
    Password = Decrypt(m.Password),
    login_Id = m.login_Id,
    UserType = "Documents Scanned",
    countID = m.docCount
 }).ToList();
```

From this list, when Id is 0 then assign UserType="UnKnown".

How can I do that?

Comment: _UserType = (m.UserID == 0 ? "UnKnown : "Documents Scanned"),_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
UserType = "Documents Scanned"
```

with

```
UserType = m.UserId != 0 ? "Documents Scanned" : "UnKnown"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Model.UserSetUp> objUserSetUp = objUserSetUp1.Select(m => new Model.UserSetUp()
        {
            Id = m.UserId,
            FirstName = m.FirstName,
            SurName = m.SurName,
            Computer_Name = m.Computer_Name,
            IP_Address = m.IP_Address,
            LogInTime = m.LogInTime,
            UserName = Decrypt(m.UserName),
            Password = Decrypt(m.Password),
            login_Id = m.login_Id,
            UserType = m.UserId == 0 ? "UnKnown" :"Documents Scanned",
            countID = m.docCount
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check it when setting up the list:

```
List<Model.UserSetUp> objUserSetUp = objUserSetUp1.Select(m => new Model.UserSetUp()
        {
            Id = m.UserId,
            FirstName = m.FirstName,
            SurName = m.SurName,
            Computer_Name = m.Computer_Name,
            IP_Address = m.IP_Address,
            LogInTime = m.LogInTime,
            UserName = Decrypt(m.UserName),
            Password = Decrypt(m.Password),
            login_Id = m.login_Id,
            UserType = m.UserId == 0 ? "Unknown" : "Documents Scanned",
            countID = m.docCount
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [inline condition operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

i.e.

```
UserType = (m.id != 0) ? "Documents Scanned" : "UnKnown",
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a ternary operator for this.

instead of

```
UserType = "Documents Scanned",
```

you can type

```
UserType = m.UserId == 0 ? UserType="UnKnown" :"Documents Scanned",
```